# multiple random numbers on one page /refresh

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate multiple unique hashes on one page and this script is not working. I keep getting only one number repeated 3 times instead of 3 unique numbers. I know i can create hash1, hash2, and hash3 functions but that is too much code.

```
<?php
  $seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH';
  $hash = sha1(uniqid($seed . mt_rand(), true));
  $hash = substr($hash, 0, 10);
?>

<? echo $hash; ?><br>
<? echo $hash; ?><br>
<? echo $hash; ?><br>
```

Comment: There appears to be only one assigning of a hash value to the `$hash` variable. Why would it be different for each `echo`?

Answer (score 4):

you can just make a function and then call that

```
<?php

function makeHash(){
    $seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH';
    $hash = sha1(uniqid($seed . mt_rand(), true));
    $hash = substr($hash, 0, 10);

    return $hash;
}

?>


<?php echo makeHash(); ?><br>

<?php echo makeHash(); ?><br>

<?php echo makeHash(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Regenerate `$hash` each time you need a new value. Otherwise, obviously, the variable you assigned the first random value to will have the same value no matter how many times you look at it, if the value is never changed.

Answer (score 2):

You're only setting the value of `$hash` once, and then calling for that value three times. It looks to me like you want to create a function that generates a unique value:

```
function hash(){
  $seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH';
  $hash = sha1( uniqid( $seed . mt_rand(), true ) );
  return substr( $hash, 0, 10 );
}

echo hash() . '<br />';
echo hash() . '<br />';
echo hash();
```

If the seed isn't intended to be immutable, you could pass it in via a parameter:

```
function hash( $seed = 'defaultval' ) {
  $hash = sha1( uniqid( $seed . mt_rand(), true ) );
  return substr( $hash, 0, 10 );
}

echo hash( 'sEedOne' );
echo hash( 'seEDtWO' );
echo hash( 'SEed...' );
```

Comment: Hmm... Why is it you and @Robot Woods' answer have the same `$seed`? Did this come from a PHP manual page?

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's the seed provided in the OP. It appears we both copy/pasted/modified the author's code.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It'd be more accurate to call it a salt, and you'll find a bunch of info if you search for that term instead (hash salt).

Comment: @MatthewScharley - I realize(d) that. I'm splitting my focus between the Rangers/Cards game, Facebook, SO and a couple other things. Too many, I suppose... Not paying enough attention to any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make part of your code a function to call it multiple times.

```
function hash(){
  $seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH';
  $hash = sha1(uniqid($seed . mt_rand(), true));
  return substr($hash, 0, 10);
}

<? echo hash(); ?><br>

<? echo hash(); ?><br>

<? echo hash(); ?><br>
```

Comment: Am I dreaming the `$seed` variable here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function make_hash($seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH', $length = 16) {
    if (16 > $length) $length = 16;
    return substr(sha1(uniqid($seed . mt_rand(), true)), 0, $length);
}

?>


<?php

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    echo make_hash('yourtexthere', 25);
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
```